# Order by conditions in SQL

Tags: sql

How to order by condition?
Example:
I have items where ready_date exists in one, and doesn't in others.
First I want make NULL items stay first after:
What I wanna do is something like:

```
WHERE ready_date=NULL order by id DESC, WHERE ready_date != NULL order by id ASC
```

How to do this??

Answer (score 2):

You can order by a boolean condition; in MySQL that is treated as 1 (true) or 0 (false) in a numeric context. You can then use that condition to flip the sign of `id` so that when the condition is true it effectively orders descending, otherwise ascending. As I understand your question, this should work:

```
ORDER BY ready_date IS NULL DESC,
         (CASE WHEN ready_date IS NULL THEN -id ELSE id END) ASC
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e9d309fac4b10dd836655491c446cb32)